# I can not get mongoose/node.js to retrieve data properly. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to get node.js to write to the console the data in the table, my other tables work.

Whenever I try I get the following output:

```
NO ERROR!
QUERY:{"emitted":{"complete":[[]]},"_events":{}}
```

Am I missing something in the Schema definition?
Any help would be appreciated.
- Eric

The following is from the mongo shell :

```
> db.userAssessments.find({})
{ "accountId" : "509683edcb884b0000000001", "created" : ISODate("2013-01-12T03:31:20.723Z"), "_id" : ObjectId("50f0d9084469766bb7000001") }
```

This is my js:

```
var userAssessmentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    accountId : String,
    created : Date,
    id: String
});

ANALYZER.userAssessments = mongoose.model('userAssessments', userAssessmentsSchema);
ANALYZER.analyzeAssessment = function() {
    var query = ANALYZER.userAssessments.find({}).exec(function(err, ass) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("NO ERROR!");
            console.log("QUERY:" + JSON.stringify(query));
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR!");
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the `find` query is passed to the `exec` callback as the second parameter (`ass` in your code).  The return value you assign to `query` is the [`Promise`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise) object returned from [`exec`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec).

**UPDATE**

Your other problem is that Mongoose [pluralizes and lower-cases](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L22) the model name to derive the collection name if you don't provide one.  To make it use the `userAssessments` collection instead of `userassessments` you need to provide that collection name in the `mongoose.model` call.

So your code should be like this instead:

```
ANALYZER.userAssessments = mongoose.model(
    'userAssessments', userAssessmentsSchema, 'userAssessments');

ANALYZER.analyzeAssessment = function() {
    ANALYZER.userAssessments.find({}).exec(function(err, ass) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("NO ERROR!");
            console.log("QUERY:" + JSON.stringify(ass));
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR!");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What are you seeing logged after this change?

Comment: @EricW See updated answer.  It's likely using the wrong collection name.